# How to create a Cassandra copy to a test machine?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise

We have a staging environment which runs a one node cluster completely separate from our production environment.  What I'd like to do is copy this one node cluster over to a test machine that I have for the sole purpose of testing.

What is the correct way to do this?  The server and test server are running Centos 6.x, and the version of DSE is 4.5.1 and Cassandra 2.0.8.39

Comment: Do your staging and prod environments have the same topology? (number of nodes, DC's etc.)?

Comment: The staging topology is only a single node, production is four nodes.  But for my purposes, the test machine should have the exact same topology as the staging server, that is one node, 1 DC, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to follow the steps described in this document:

- http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_restore_c.html.

If your test cluister's topology is different from the original cluster then you will need to use a tool like a sstableloader:

- http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_snapshot_restore_t.html
- http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_move_cluster.html
- http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html